# What does "sift through the jargon" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar, metaphors

What does Mr. Richard Quest mean by "... *so we'll sift through the jargon.*" in this video script?

The number of billionaires in the world has more than doubled in the last five years. There's more ideas, more opportunities; it's created more wealth; just not for all! As the Economic gaps widened, the issue is : " Are you getting your fair share?
***The business world has many options so we'll sift through the jargon***. Making you better informed. Ready, to get your slice of the pie!
....................................

Note:I wrote the video script. (Not sure it's accurate)

Video Info:

Name: CNN International "Quest Means Business" promo

Length: 30 second

*[Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZ8HyV0_DGQ)*

Comment: Don't be quick to assign meaning. It's an impressive sounding bit of puffery, but "sifting" through the jargon doesn't actually mean anything **or** he's tortured a metaphor and is planning to educate you as to the meaning of the jargon so you can sift bad options from good options (of the many options available in business). I think I'm going long on option B, with a small short position on option A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One definition from Oxford Dictionaries Online fits perfectly:

> *[Sift](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sift)*
>
> verb
>   2 Examine (something) thoroughly so as to isolate that which is
>   most important:
>   *until we sift the evidence ourselves, we can’t comment objectively*

The jargon on both sides of a controversial issue is designed to confound reasonable examination with obfuscation. Mr. Quest seems to be offering to ***examine*** the jargon of the business world ***very thoroughly*** to remove the obfuscation, and identify the real issues. Unfortunately, he seems to employ his own brand of jargon!